# How to compare sqlite TIMESTAMP values

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

I have an Sqlite database in which I want to select rows of which the value in a TIMESTAMP column is before a certain date. I would think this to be simple but I can't get it done. I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM logged_event WHERE logged_event.CREATED_AT < '2010-05-28 16:20:55'
```

and various variations on it, like with the date functions. I've read http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html and I would expect that the column would be a numeric type, and that the comparison would be done on the unix timestamp value. Apparantly not. Anyone who can help? If it matters, I'm trying this out in Sqlite Expert Personal.

Edit:

Here's type table description:

```
CREATE TABLE [logged_event]
(
[id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[created_at] TIMESTAMP,
[name] VARCHAR(64),
[data] VARCHAR(512)
);
```

And the test data:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1,'2010-05-28T15:36:56+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(2,'2010-05-28T16:20:49+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(3,'2010-05-28T16:20:51+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(4,'2010-05-28T16:20:52+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(5,'2010-05-28T16:20:53+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(6,'2010-05-28T16:20:55+0200','test','test');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(7,'2010-05-28T16:20:57+0200','test','test');
```

Comment: What version of SQLite are you running?  The 3.x.x documentation does not define what a column called TIMESTAMP is casted to in type affinity.  http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Sqlite 3. Because everything that is not in a limited set of text types (TEXT, BLOB, a few others) is numeric, according to the documentation, I assumed that TIMESTAMP would be a numeric type.

Of note is that I'm creating this table through the Propel ORM mapper, and it's an auto-generated table, so I can't easily switch to another type. I guess if I could get this column to behave as a DATETIME I'd be half way there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The issue is with the way you've inserted data into your table: the `+0200` syntax doesn't match any of [SQLite's time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

1. YYYY-MM-DD
2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
8. HH:MM
9. HH:MM:SS
10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
11. now
12. DDDDDDDDDD

Changing it to use the SS.SSS format works correctly:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Foo (created_at TIMESTAMP);
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo VALUES('2010-05-28T15:36:56+0200');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE foo.created_at < '2010-05-28 16:20:55';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE DATETIME(foo.created_at) < '2010-05-28 16:20:55';
sqlite> INSERT INTO Foo VALUES('2010-05-28T15:36:56.200');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE DATETIME(foo.created_at) < '2010-05-28 16:20:55';
2010-05-28T15:36:56.200
```

If you absolutely can't change the format when it is inserted, you might have to fall back to doing something "clever" and modifying the actual string (i.e. to replace the `+` with a `.`, etc.).

---

(original answer)

You haven't described what kind of data is contained in your `CREATED_AT` column. If it indeed a datetime, it will compare correctly against a string:

```
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('now');
2010-05-28 16:33:10
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('now') < '2011-01-01 00:00:00';
1
```

If it is stored as a unix timestamp, you need to call `DATETIME` function with the second argument as `'unixepoch'` to compare against a string:

```
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME(0, 'unixepoch');
1970-01-01 00:00:00
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME(0, 'unixepoch') < '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
1
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME(0, 'unixepoch') == DATETIME('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
1
```

If neither of those solve your problem (and even if they do!) you should **always** post some data so that other people can reproduce your problem.  You should even feel free to come up with a *subset* of your original data that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yes I saw these examples in the manual too. What I want to do is SELECT * from table WHERE column < '2010-05-23 14:32:29'; and I presume I need to add a function in there somewhere in some form but I have no idea how.

Comment: Thank you, indeed the timezone specifier did it. This was exacerbated by Sqlite Expert not showing that part - it only showed up when I did a command line SELECT for posting the test data here. Have hacked a solution into my program to leave out the timezone part.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's support for date/time types is very limited.  You may have to roll-your-own method for maintaining time information.  At least, that's what I did.

You can define your own stored-functions for doing comparisons using the SQLite create_function() API.

Comment: Note that the problem I had involved _adding_ time periods, though, not comparing.  I think Mark's answer is probably better in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, it's entirely reasonable to include a timezone specifier; see the text "formats 2 through 10 can . . ." at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
However, the issue is that only the date functions interpret timestamps as dates.  So for actual comparison, you need to either pass the timestamp through a date function or store things such that string comparison works.
One approach would be to code your application such that  you called datetime  on every value that you insert and on every literal value in a select statement.
However, simply not including the time zone as suggested by the existing answer may be easier in many applications.