# Comparing created_at fields with PGSQL on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

My question is sort of like the one found here:

[How to compare sqlite TIMESTAMP values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930768/how-to-compare-sqlite-timestamp-values)

Except that the answer doesn't work for PostgreSQL. Is there any way to compare two created_at values made by Rails with a PG function?

Here's what I want to do (I know this doesn't work, DATETIME doesn't work for PG):

```
EventDish.find_by_sql(["select * from ............. and DATETIME(events.created_at) < ?", other_event.created_at])
```

With the ellipses added to highlight the important part. In other words, I want to compare two Rails created_at fields (these are using whatever the default is), but I want to compare them with PG. Any suggestions? (I'm not too familiar with SQL in general, so any pure Rails solutions would also be appreciated)

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting a postgresql error? you can normally compare postgresql timestamp values with strings directly in sql, postgresql will implicitly convert the string to a timestamp to make the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do:

```
EventDish.where('created_at < ?', other_event.created_at)
```

This translates to:

```
"SELECT \"event_dishes\".* FROM \"event_dishes\" WHERE (created_at < '2011-06-10 16:39:19.557436')"
```

I would personally stay way from using `find_by_sql` unless you really need to do some complex queries.  If you can, keep it simple and let ActiveRecord do the work for you.

If you can't avoid using `find_by_sql` then just update your current query to be:

```
EventDish.find_by_sql(["select * from ............. WHERE (created_at < '#{other_event.created_at}')")
```

Comment: The problem is that it is a quite complex query... I can't post it entirely here. I've tried doing event.created_at < ?, other_event.created_at but PG can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply skip the DATETIME() function:

```
EventDish.find_by_sql(['select * from event_dish where created_at > ?', other_event.created_at])
```