# unable to form SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have orders table in which orders are stored based on order received datetime(timestamp).

Now, I want only the orders between 2 dates, and that too, for everyday in those dates, between 2 and 4 PM only.

How can I achieve this, preferably in a single SQL query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930768/how-to-compare-sqlite-timestamp-values

Comment: @MiikaL. : frankly sayimg, I'm totally clueless about how to achieve this in one query, although i have already done it using loops by first fetching between days, and then for each day, between specified times

Comment: @Habib.OSU : sory dear, but that's not related to the question i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not absolutely certain of the SQLLite syntax, but something along the lines of the following might get you on the right track:

```
SELECT *
FROM [orders]
WHERE orderReceived >= @startDate
    AND orderReceived < @endDate
    AND (strftime("%H", orderReceived) = "14"
        OR strftime("%H", orderReceived) = "15")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to you **where** clause:

```
time(mytimecol) > '14:00:00' AND time(mytimecol) < '16:00:00'
```

CF [date and time functions in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).