# ORMLite query date format issue

Tags: sqlite, date-format, ormlite

I want to convert sqlite query to Ormlite query.

```
SELECT * FROM Test where strftime('%m-%Y',Date)='11-2001'
```

I could not format date column like above query.

How to format Date column in Ormlite as `MM-yyyy`?
Thanks.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930768/how-to-compare-sqlite-timestamp-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is the exact SQL that you want to use then you can use the `Where.raw(...)` method:

```
QueryBuilder<Test, Integer> qb = testDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().raw("strftime('%m-%Y',Date) = '11-2001'");
List<Test> results = qb.query();
```

However, this only seems to work if the date field is stored as a `DATE_STRING` type:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING)
Date date;
```

The issue is that by default the Xerial JDBC driver is storing the date in the format:

```
2012-07-19 09:58:18.36
```

Which does not [quite] match one of the approved Sqlite formats which are:

1. YYYY-MM-DD
2. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
3. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
4. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
5. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
6. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
7. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
8. HH:MM
9. HH:MM:SS
10. HH:MM:SS.SSS
11. now
12. DDDDDDDDDD

When you change it to `DataType.DATE_STRING` then it will be stored as the following which seems to work:

```
2012-07-19 10:03:49.000991
```

For more info, see the Sqlite docs on date functions.   Unfortunately, the documentation does *not* fully explain that the database values need to be in a certain format:

> http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html