# how to select/delete all rows except within 24 hours before from current time in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a table named **daily_mood** and it has three (3) columns, looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_mood (moodid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,mood TEXT,mooddate DATETIME)
```

[image]

it's data looks like that:
   [image]

Now, i want to select/delete all rows except from current date to before 24 hours exactly according to mooddate column.

i tried this query like:

```
SELECT *from daily_mood where mooddate>=datetime('now', '-1 day');
```

the result should be 1 row(last one) from above data.but here comes 2.like[image]

results should be the last row. Anyone can help me? thanks.

Comment: Not an sqllite developer but I would suggest you view the results of SELECT datetime('now', '-1 day'); and verify it is what you'd expect.

Comment: Are you saying the date outputted isn't what you'd expect?  Just to be clear, I was recommending a way of debugging, not a fix for your problem.

Comment: What happens when you execute the query that you've posted? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @jmilloy: i need the data which is exactly within 24 hours from the current time. the results come 2 rows in above. but it should be the last 1. it just calculate a whole day from current but i need within 24 hours exact. so final result should be the last row in above pic.

Comment: I see. You need to compare timestamps and not dates. There is a detailed explanation here that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930768/how-to-compare-sqlite-timestamp-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);


String query = "SELECT * from daily_mood WHERE mooddate >= " + "'" + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()) + "'";
```

Comment: can u give me the raw sqlite query?

Comment: SELECT * from daily_mood WHERE mooddate >= '2012-09-22 12:05:00'

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
        Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar removeBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
        removeBefore.set(cd.get(Calendar.YEAR), cd.get(Calendar.MONTH),(cd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7));//Here set day before old data to be removed.

try{

  sqlDatabase=getSqlWritable();
            rowaffeted=sqlDatabase.delete(TB3, TB3_Date +" < ? ", new String[]{df.format(removeBefore.getTime())});


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//you need to use following method

```
public SQLiteDatabase getSqlWritable(){
        if(dbhelper == null)
            dbhelper=new DbOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        return dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```