# How delete entries in sqlite database based on timestamp on android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My Android app has an SQLite database table with entries as follows:

```
USER_ID | NAME | MESSAGE | TIMESTAMP
```

where the timestamp is stored in a  String in format:

```
"2012-10-10T03:14:32+0000"
```

I'm looking for a way to delete entries older than 3 days.

The table is likely to have less than 3,000 rows at a time.

I'm new to SQL and my question is how can I approach this in SQL for SQLite? Is there a less expensive way to do this in SQL than to iterate all posts in Java?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930768/how-to-compare-sqlite-timestamp-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [this doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Another way is to use the fact that the date format you use can be sorted directly as a string (lexicographical order).

1. In java code, you build the string representing the datetime threshold (Now minus 3 days)
2. And just compare the strings in SQL in the where clause

   SELECT *
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE TIMESTAMP >= 'The date I built in Java'

Most of the time, Timestamps and datetimes are stored as ticks in SQLite, which involves int comparaison (much faster).